# Messages in Virtual Topic not consumed by consumer queue

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, virtual, consumer

I am trying to use a queue in activemq to dequeue messages from a virtual topic. I tried sending some messages and it is showing up in the topic under "message enqueued" but it is not able to be consumed.

The virtual topic name that i created was VirtualTopic.AA and the consumer is called Consumer.client1.VirtualTopic.AA.

In the consumer.client1.VirtualTopic.AA, i can see that there is a consumer but it is just not able to dequeue messages from the virtual topic.

Anyone knows why this is happening ? Do i need to change some settings in the configuration in the xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

When you publish to a virtual topic using Spring's JmsTemplate, you need to configure it for a topic by setting the `pubSubDomain` property to "true".

From the [JmsTemplate documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsTemplate.html):

> If you want to use dynamic destination creation, you must specify the type of JMS destination to create, using the "pubSubDomain" property. For other operations, this is not necessary. Point-to-Point (Queues) is the default domain.

And in [JmsDestinationAccessor#setPubSubDomain](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/destination/JmsDestinationAccessor.html#setPubSubDomain-boolean-):

> pubSubDomain - "true" for the Publish/Subscribe domain (Topics), "false" for the Point-to-Point domain (Queues)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular `jmsTemplate` from `org.springframework.jms.core` without setting `pubSubDomain` with `true` value if you pass `ActiveMQTopic` instance with the name of your topic.

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(new ActiveMQTopic("topicName"));
```