# How to consume a message from a virtual topic with ActiveMQ?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I'm publishing a message to a virtual topic named **VirtualTopic.Orders** (through the spring-jms). I  publish the message to ActiveMQ without any problem and I can see the message in the **VirtualTopic.Orders** queue, but I can't consume it. Here is my JmsTemplate bean declaration:

```
<bean id="jmsTemplateBusinessEvents" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I have set pubSubDomain as true because of [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441859/messages-in-virtual-topic-not-consumed-by-consumer-queue).

I also changed the configuration file activemq.xml as explained [here](https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html):

```
<destinationInterceptors>
    <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        <virtualDestinations>
            <virtualTopic name="VirtualTopic.>" prefix="Consumer.*.VirtualTopic.>" selectorAware="false"/>
        </virtualDestinations>
     </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```

And here is my consumer pointing to the **Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Orders** queue:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" init-method="start"
          lazy-init="false">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destinationName" value="Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.Orders"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="processStatusHandler"/>
</bean>
```

If anyone can help me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already encountered the problem. The consumer prefix value is incorrect must be:

```
<destinationInterceptors>
    <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        <virtualDestinations>
            <virtualTopic name="VirtualTopic.>" prefix="Consumer.*.>" selectorAware="false"/>
        </virtualDestinations>
     </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```